# Intersection of dictionary of sets

Tags: python, dictionary, set, intersection, set-intersection

So I have a dictionary that was made from reading a file and making a key for each word found in that file with the value being a set of line numbers that the word occurs on. Here is an example of the dictionary from a file.

```
{'we': {4}, 'created': {4}, 'into': {2}, 'cant': {6}, 'imagination': {3}, 'with': {4}, 'nature': {2}, 'genius': {7}, 'gravity': {6}, 'of': {1, 3, 5}, 'rather': {1}, 'has': {7}, 'difference': {7}, 'try': {1}, 'better': {2}, 'used': {4}, 'value': {1}, 'between': {7}, 'blame': {6}, 'problems': {4}, 'is': {3, 7}, 'everything': {2}, 'not': {1, 3}, 'to': {1}, 'intelligence': {3}, 'thinking': {4}, 'them': {4}, 'deep': {2}, 'become': {1}, 'falling': {6}, 'for': {6}, 'character': {5}, 'when': {4}, 'will': {2}, 'solve': {4}, 'limits': {7}, 'same': {4}, 'weakness': {5}, 'and': {2, 7}, 'but': {1, 3}, 'love': {6}, 'knowledge': {3}, 'understand': {2}, 'then': {2}, 'man': {1}, 'our': {4}, 'attitude': {5}, 'in': {6}, 'the': {3, 4, 7}, 'that': {7}, 'sign': {3}, 'look': {2}, 'stupidity': {7}, 'cannot': {4}, 'its': {7}, 'true': {3}, 'success': {1}, 'becomes': {5}, 'you': {2, 6}}
```

What I need to do is take user entered space separated words (that I made into a list) and search the dictionary for the intersection of lines that they are all on. For example if the user enters "the" then it would return 3, 4, 7 and if they entered "the is" would return 3, 7.

Here is what I have come up with so far just trying to get it to work for 1 word:

```
inp_lst = inp_str.strip().split()

print("The co-occurance for: " + ", ".join(inp_lst))


for word in inp_lst:

    word = word.strip().strip(string.punctuation).lower()\
        .replace("'","").replace("-","")

    if word in D: 
        word_set = D[word]

    else:
        return None


cooccurance_lst = list(word_set)

return cooccurance_lst.sort()
```

And everything I try keeps returning None.

Comment: Your first problem is calling `inp_str.strip().split()`. `string.split()` called with no arguments splits the string on each character, so `"the".split()` returns `["t", "h", "e"]`. Try fixing that as a first move.

Comment: To clarify, you should use `inp_str.strip().split(" ")`, which will split the string on each space, the behavior I assume you want.

Comment: @DW42 Um, `>>> "the".split() -> ['the']`, you are probably thinking of `list("the")`. If no separator for `str.split` is provided then it will default to whitespace.

Comment: My apologies; I confused `.split()` and `.split('')` (which may now be depreciated) without checking.

Comment: Another thing to consider is that `cooccurance_lst.sort()` will return `None` as your are sorting in place, you will need to sort then return or `return sorted(cooccurance_lst)`

Comment: @StevenSummers thanks, that was another big problem I was having!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume `uinput` is the list of user-entered words and `D` is your dictionary, e.g.:

```
uinput = "the is".split()
```

Then you can go over the `uinput`, use each word as a dictionary key, fetch its value, and finally take the intersection, exactly as your question's title suggests:

```
set.intersection(*[D[x] for x in uinput if x in D])
#{3, 7}
```

Comment: You probably need an `in` check. `set.intersection(*(d[x] for x in uinput if x in d))`

Comment: @StevenSummers Fair enough.

Comment: what that * does here?

Comment: took me a while to realize that 'D' is the name of the dictionary created by OP. He does not specify that anywhere does he?

Comment: @Dandekar No he does not.

Comment: I apologize, i probably should have specified this. This answer did seem to get me what I needed though. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

this is the problem :

```
 if word not in D: 
    word_set = D[word]
```

should be

```
if word in D: 
    word_set = D[word]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the line `if word not in D:`. In that line, you make sure any input that *is* in `D` is deferred to the `else`, thereby returning `None` (I'm assuming this all takes place within a function, as that's the only place where `return` statements make sense). Changing it to `if word in D:` should allow you to continue debugging.

Comment: Yeah I fixed it in the question. I had originally had the if else there backwards thinking it might help but it didn't so I changed it back. Thanks.

Comment: Aside from that, @DYZ 's answer seems to fit.